# Heroku db migration error: PG::DuplicateObject: ERROR: constraint for relation already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, database-migration

I'm trying to deploy to heroku. First, I pushed to GIT and to heroku (using `git push heroku`). Then I wanted to migrate the db using `heroku run rake db:migrate` but after migration partially got the following error message:

```
-- add_foreign_key(:members, :organizations)
   (16.5ms)  ALTER TABLE "members" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_43c258b686"
FOREIGN KEY ("organization_id")
  REFERENCES "organizations" ("id")

PG::DuplicateObject: ERROR:  constraint "fk_rails_43c258b686" for relation "members" already exists
: ALTER TABLE "members" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_43c258b686"
FOREIGN KEY ("organization_id")
  REFERENCES "organizations" ("id")

   (1.2ms)  ROLLBACK
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DuplicateObject: ERROR:  constraint "fk_rails_43c258b686" for relation "members" already exists
: ALTER TABLE "members" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_43c258b686"
FOREIGN KEY ("organization_id")
  REFERENCES "organizations" ("id")
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
...etc.
```

I have no data to loose, so tried `heroku pg:reset DATABASE` (also since I have tempered with existing migration files rather then everytime create a new one) and then `heroku run rake db:migrate` but with the same result.

In development, running `rake db:migrate` functions properly (I also used `bundle exec rake db:reset` to reset the development db). I don't seem to be experiencing problems in development, so it seems a Heroku problem. Does anyone have an idea what might be causing this?

Perhaps also relevant: I'm using the puma server of Heroku.

**Update:** One of the migration files contains:

```
1  def change
2    create_table :members do |t|
3      t.references :organization,   index: true,  foreign_key: true
4      t.string :email,              null: false
5      etc
6      t.timestamps null: false
7    end
8    add_foreign_key :members, :organizations
9    add_index :members, [:organization_id, :username]
10 end
```

Are it perhaps lines 3 and 8 that are double? If so, what should I delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simply indicates that there is already a foreign key from "members"."organization_id" to "organizations"."id". You might confirm whether that is so by examining the production database after the migration fails.

The foreign key must be getting created already by a previous migration, possibly when the members table is created. Are you using PostgreSQL in development? Maybe you're using a database that is less fussy about duplicate constraint definitions, or which does not create them under the circumstances that are creating the previous one on PostgreSQL in production.

Comment: I use SQLite for development and PostgreSQL (via Heroku) for deployment.  Am I correct to understand that I am probably in the migration file defining the foreign key two times? I have added an update in my original post. Could you perhaps confirm that one of the lines in the update should be deleted?

Comment: @Nick: (1) Stop developing on top of SQLite if you're going to be deploying on something else. (2) The `foreign_key: true` is probably creating the FK and then `add_foreign_key` tries to add it again.

Comment: Yes, removing line 8 of the update in the original post solved it. Will do some research to find out how to switch SQLite in development to PostgeSQL.